# Axios interceptor for JWT refresh token

Tags: vue.js, axios, jwt, interceptor

Axios interceptor generates new refresh token for each 401.

I've build an interceptor that checks each axios response for 401, if there is a 401 because the access token is expired- I send an axios request to generate a new access token. The interceptor works great but my problem is, because I'm getting updates in an interval (meaning I send five axios requests at the same time), all of them return 401 and each one generates a new access tokens.
My client is vue.js with pinia and the server is python.

Here is my iterceptor:

```
/ Helper function to refresh access token
async function refreshAccessToken(refreshToken, module) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(`${VITE_API_ROOT_URL}${VITE_API_PORT}${AUTH_SVC_PREFIX}/api/v1/token/refresh/`, { refresh: refreshToken });
    const newAccessToken = response.data.access;
    module.setAccessToken(newAccessToken);
    return newAccessToken;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error refreshing access token:", error);
    throw error;
  }
}

// Axios interceptor to handle expired access tokens
const axios_interceptor = axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (res) => res,
  async (error) => {
    const originalRequest = error.config;
    const userModule = userState();
    // Check if the request was unauthorized (HTTP 401)
    if (error.response && error.response.status === 401 && originalRequest.url !== "/login") {
      const refreshToken = userModule.getRefreshToken;
      const decodedRefreshToken = jwtDecode(refreshToken);

      // Check if refresh token has expired
      if (decodedRefreshToken.exp <= Date.now() / 1000) {
        // Refresh token has expired, logout user and redirect to login page
        userModule.logout();
        router.push({ name: "login" });
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }

      // Refresh access token and retry request
      if (!originalRequest._retry) {
        originalRequest._retry = true;

        try {
          const newAccessToken = await refreshAccessToken(refreshToken, userModule);
          originalRequest.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${newAccessToken}`;
          console.log("I'm done!");
          return axios(originalRequest);
        } catch (error) {
          userModule.logout();
          router.push({ name: "login" });
          return Promise.reject(error);
        }
      }
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

export default axios_interceptor;
```

I tried changing my interceptor to make an unresolved requests queue, but they are not returning to the component who sent them.

Any ideas or packages to help me at this point? Unfortunately I can't change the interval for the updates